# How to deserialize into a List<String> using the XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to deserialize the XML below into class, with the `Components` deserialized into a `List<string>`, but can't figure out how to do so.  The deserializer is working fine for all the other properties, but not `Components`.  Anyone know how to do this?

```xml
<ArsAction>
  <CustomerName>Joe Smith</CustomerName>
  <LoginID>jdsmith</LoginID>
  <TicketGroup>DMS</TicketGroup>
  <Software>Visio 2007 Pro</Software>
  <Components>
    <Component>Component 1</Component>
    <Component>Component 2</Component>
  </Components>
  <Bldg>887</Bldg>
  <Room>1320p</Room>
</ArsAction>
```

Comment: Please post the class you're trying to serialize and deserialize.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Add a property like this to hold the list of Components:

```
[XmlArray()]
public List<Component> Components { get; set; }
```

Edit: Sorry I misread that.  You want to read it into a collection of strings.  I just tried this below and it worked on your sample.  The key is just to setup the correct xml serialization attributes.

```
public class ArsAction
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Component")]
    public List<string> Components { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [XmlArray] is optional if the property name is the same as tag name

Comment: [XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Component")] can be shorten as [XmlArrayItem("Component")]. Tested on .Net 4.0