# Flatten xml for deserializing

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm deserializing an xml and for that I use these classes

```
[DataContract(Name = "Validation")]
public class FieldValidationModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Annotation { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Collection<ValidationPlanType> PlanTypes { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="PlanType")]
public class ValidationPlanType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It works, but ideally I would like to use only one class

```
[DataContract(Name = "Validation")]
public class FieldValidationModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Annotation { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> PlanTypes { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried to use

```
[DataMember]
[XmlArray, XmlArrayItem(Namespace="PlanType")]
public List<string> PlanTypes { get; set; }
```

with no luck, if I could do so the nodes will be flatten from what I have to use now

```
<Validation>
  <Annotation>TestAnnotation</Annotation>
  <PlanTypes>
    <PlanType>
      <Name>PlanA</Name>
    </PlanType>
    <PlanType>
      <Name>PlanB</Name>
    </PlanType>
  </PlanTypes>
</Validation>
```

to the more readable

```
<Validation>
  <Annotation>TestAnnotation</Annotation>
  <PlanTypes>
    <PlanType>PlanA</PlanType>
    <PlanType>PlanB</PlanType>
  </PlanTypes>
</Validation>
```

Thanks

Comment: a bit fuzzy what you are after

Comment: Sorry for that, I understand you that's no clear (no sure about the sense of fuzzy). What I'm trying to achieve is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208643/how-to-deserialize-into-a-liststring-using-the-xmlserializer-in-c-sharp for my PlanTypes

Comment: so you would like to use second model that will create first xml or vice versa?

Comment: I would like to be able to deserialize the second model in the second class, the one using a List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but should work:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Validation")]
public class FieldValidationModel
{
      [DataMember]
      public string Annotation { get; set; }

      [DataMember]
      public PlanTypeCollection PlanTypes { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName="PlanType")]
public class PlanTypeCollection : Collection<string>  {}
```