# How to parse XML in c# with same tag names?

Tags: c#, xml

My goal is to get `List<String>` of  `<AccessKey>`'s from XML string.
How onw would parse such XML?

```
    <Project>
        <AccessKeys>
            <AccessKey>key_1</AccessKey>
            <AccessKey>key_2</AccessKey>
        </AccessKeys>
    </Project>
```

I've tried

```
[XmlArray("AccessKeys"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(AccessKeyData), ElementName = "AccessKey")]
public List<AccessKeyData> AccessKeys = new List<AccessKeyData>();

    [Serializable]
    public class AccessKeyData
    {
        public string AccessKey;
    }
```

I have no problem to get back single   `<AccessKey>`
When i have more   `<AccessKey>` i get back empty lists/arrays.

Comment: Do you definitely need to use XML serialization at all? I'd just use: `var keys = XDocument.Load(...).Descendants("AccessKey").Select(element => element.Value).ToList()` or similar.

Comment: Assuming your `AccessKeys` property belongs to some `Project` class, use `[XmlArray("AccessKeys"), XmlArrayItem("AccessKey")] public public List<string> AccessKeys { get; set; }` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208702) by [Brian Ensink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254/brian-ensink) to [How to deserialize into a List<String> using the XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1208643).  Demo here:https://dotnetfiddle.net/l5JQK6.  I'd propose to close this as a duplicate, agree?  Or do you require the extra `AccessKeyData` class?

Comment: I agree with @dbc that this looks like a duplicate of the linked answer from Brian Ensink, unless you specifically need an array of that class to be populated somewhere instead of a list of strings. I would think it should be easy enough, assuming you can get the list of strings, to concatenate them into whatever form you would like. Maybe  add a `List<string> AccessKeyList` that gets set, and then make AccessKey a property to concatenate those into a single string? If you really want arrays of classes you could just make a method or function to do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I do not need that. And it looks like it does the trick. 
I just wasn't aware of XDocument class.

Comment: @dbc  It looks like a duplicate. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly At this point List<string> works for me, than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Project>
        <AccessKeys>
            <AccessKey>key_1</AccessKey>
            <AccessKey>key_2</AccessKey>
        </AccessKeys>
    </Project>");

    List<String> listOfString = xdoc.Descendants("AccessKey")
      .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

    Console.Write(listOfString);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for!  
I wasn't  aware of XDocument class.